# Wine 1.3.25 update broke sound, how do I go back?

Tags: audio, ubuntu-10.10, wine

Last Friday's Wine update to 1.3.25 broke sound, how do I go back to the previous version of Wine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backed up my wine prefix folder; used Synaptic to remove anything wine; and then installed 1.3.24. My sound seems to be fine now. I did not need my backup. Applications and configurations are as they were before.

Answer (score 1):

In synaptic, search for wine and select it. Then go to Package->Force Version, and pick one. Once you've applied (and thus downgraded), search for wine and select it again, this time going to Package->Lock Version. If you want to upgrade it in the future you will have to unlock it, but in the meantime it won't nag you about having updated software.

Comment: Force Version is greyed out